# Can an Oracle trigger be disabled for the current session?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'd like to disable a specific trigger on a table prior to inserting data into it, but **without affecting other users** that may be changing data in that same table.  I can't find any documented way to do this.  This is Oracle 11g.

The best solution I've been able to come up with is to create a session variable and have my application set that to some value that the trigger checks for prior to doing its work.

*Obligatory anti-trigger comment:* I hate triggers.

Comment: :I dnt think that , you can disable trigger for a specific session ,what you can do ,to change the trigger code ,and will execute for other session .Put a if condition ` userenv('SESSIONID') `

Comment: +1 for hating triggers

Comment: @DavidAldridge - sorry you hate triggers.  They have their place and can be very useful - but if misused they can cause maintenance nightmares.  (Don't ask me how I know :-).

Comment: If you find it necessary to disable a trigger for some particular set of conditions I suggest that you're looking at a fine opportunity to refactor the code in question.

Comment: @BobJarvis as part of the business logic for an application, I think triggers suck. For out-of-application logging and monitoring though, they're great. But of course what people use them for is the former, mostly I suppose because they had a college assignment that required using them as part of business logic, or even worse to enforce a constraint. Their assignment didn't include debugging it afterwards.

Comment: @BobJarvis - I am actually disabling the trigger as part of my refactoring.  The trigger is about 2000 lines of terrible, but it must remain in place because other applications outside of our control rely on it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge et. al. - regarding business logic in triggers, we are in complete agreement.  Around here we've got a fairly major system that depends on an INSTEAD OF trigger that does something that triggers another trigger, which triggers yet more triggers, etc, blah.  The original project lead and her developers have all fled the company (and perhaps the country :-), and we have as much as possible left bad enough alone.  It's on my list of things to be refactored, just as soon as we clean off the critical project list.  Yep, just about any century now...  :-)

Comment: @radium - you might consider, as part of your refactoring, pulling  the business functionality out of the trigger and putting it into a procedure, then having the trigger invoke the procedure.  That would at least get you part of the way there - then as time permits (stop laughing - that is **so** rude... :-) you might be able to handle further refactoring on an application-by-application and case-by-case basis.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a variable to an existing package spec (or create a new package):

```
enable_trigger boolean := true;
```

Surround the code in the trigger with:

```
if enable_trigger then

end if;
```

When you want to "disable" the trigger set the variable to false.

A Best Practice would be to put the variable in the body and write a set procedure and a get function.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think that disabling trigger is possible for a particular session is possible in oracle or other rdbms .

My solution is that ,if you know the CURRENT_USER or the session_id from which you login ,than you can put a condition in the trigger .

```
  IF SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') <> '<XYZ>' THEN
    --do the operation

  END IF;
```

This condition you need to put in your trigger

Comment: Exactly.  The whole point about triggers is that they fire whenever the event occurs.

Comment: @Rene: Thanks for the possible alternative ,but i am not familiar with this approach .Will need to read and do some handson on this .+1

Comment: So user XYZ will never execute the code. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @redcayuga:It depends on the condition,under what event the programmer wants to execute the code,I just advised him that you cannot diable trigger for a particular session ,and to achieve his requirement he need to change the trigger with `IF` condition,but in my opinion,you answer this question better .

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Oracle Editions are useful for this purpose? Create a different trigger in another edition and change the session to use that edition.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2.php#editions

I must confess that I have no practical experience with editions.

Comment: You may get this to work for you but that is not the intended use of Editions.

Answer (score 3):

Use [dbms_application_info.set_client_info](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.html#GUID-14484F86-44F2-4B34-B34E-0C873D323EAD) (link to oracle documentation) to set_client_info in the procedure and read it in the trigger.

**Simple example:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON   
declare
CI_Status VARCHAR2(25 BYTE):='';
begin
--set the value
dbms_application_info.set_client_info('qwerty');
-- the value is sent an out to CI_Status when you want to read it
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_CLIENT_INFO (CI_Status);
--Output the value in the console 
dbms_output.put_line('Value of CI_Status is: ' || CI_Status); 
end;
```

**In your procedure:**

```
procedure spname is
    begin
      dbms_application_info.set_client_info('qwerty');
      --Do your update
      UPDATE tableName set a=b;
      --in case you still have the sesion opened, set it to null after
      dbms_application_info.set_client_info(null);
end;
```

**In you trigger:**

```
create or replace TRIGGER Triggername
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON tablename
 FOR EACH ROW
declare
CI_Status VARCHAR2(25 BYTE):='';
begin
--Retrieve the value into CI_Status the variable
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_CLIENT_INFO(CI_Status); 
    IF INSERTING THEN
       null;
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
          IF CI_Status = 'qwerty' then
             --Do nothing since you dont want the trigger to fire
              null;
          ELSIF CI_Status is null then
            :new.tablefield:= SYSDATE;
          END IF;
    END IF;
end Triggername;
```

**To disable completely without worrying about concurrences**

```
 procedure spname is
    begin    
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER Triggername DISABLE';
      UPDATE tableName set a=b;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER Triggername ENABLE';
   end;
```